# Connect to MySQL server without MySQL on local computer

Tags: c#, mysql, server

First, excuse me if I don't use the exact terms (I may do some mistakes using terms).

I am working on one program that I develop on my personal computer.
For MySQL, I installed WampServer, so I can connect to my MySQL database (on computer).

My program will be installed on CNC machines in a workshop, without possibility to install any MySQL tool (old machines).

What I am wondering is, if I make a program using MySQL library (MySQL.Data.dll), will the program be able to connect on MySQL DataBase located on the server (of course with connection to the server).
I have no experience on that point, and that's only now I am thinking about this possible issue. Any advise will be welcome.

Comment: you need mysql client to connect to mysql remote server, Mysql.data.dll should be enough to connect to mysql.

Comment: @metal excuse me, but what do you mean by mysql client? is this an additional library? or is this a program to install? (I cannot install anything on computer)

Comment: Connecting to another computer that host's MySQL is pretty much the same as connecting on localhost. The only difference is, if you need to be able to access it outside of your local network (which, I might add, I don't recommend), you will need to port forward and tell your MySQL server to accept external connections.

Comment: if this is web app, mysql.data.dll should be in your /bin folder, if its an application, put it your GAC

Comment: @Jess if I don't make a mistake, this will be the same network (for security reasons), the only point is on these old machines, it is not possible to install any software, I just can copy my program on the machine, then execute it.

Comment: You'll be fine.

Comment: @metal it is not web app (most of time these machines have no internet), forgot to precise it, it is simple WPF App, working locally.

Comment: The only thing the program needs to connect is the MySQL.Data library.

Comment: @metal just saw your edit, so I guess there will be no problem, thanks all for your answers